# Existing LDAP is being de-commissioned, and AD will take its place, how would the jenkins user groups be effected

Tags: jenkins, ldap

My existing LDAP is being de-commissioned, and AD will take its place, please let me know how would the jenkins user groups be effected. I know this is a dry question, but I dont know how to proceed.

How do I copy the existing LDAP user groups to AD.....is there a way of doing it?

Comment: How do I copy the existing LDAP user groups to AD.....is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a question you should ask your IT Department. Ask them when the migration of LDAP groups to AD groups will be done.

If they are not planning to do so, ask them how to create new groups.

On jenkins side, you will need to configure the active directory plugin with the information your IT Department will share with you. Finally, you might need to delete the groups and enter them back in jenkins user permission page, apart from that there is no real difference between AD and LDAP groups on a jenkins admin point of view

Comment: How do I copy the existing LDAP user groups to AD.....is there a way of doing it?

Comment: I believe it is possible but I never done it. I recommend you to ask this on https://devops.stackexchange.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/